# Find correct internet protocol for given IP and PORT

Tags: powershell, windows-10, firewall, network-protocols

I'm adding firewall rules for specific IP and PORT in Windows 10. But I'm getting errors the:
**The protocol is invalid.**

**Address that I need to add:**

```
13.79.172.43/8883,443
3.250.210.0/23
3.250.243.64/26
3.251.56.0/24
3.251.62.128/25
34.245.205.0/27
18.130.91.148/30
```

**Example of what I'm using:**

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block-Wireless-In-01" -Name "Block-Wireless-In-01" -Direction Inbound -InterfaceType Wireless -Action Block -RemoteAddress 13.79.172.43 -LocalPort 8883,443 - Protocol TCP
```

**Options I have in Windows firewall settings for defining protocol are:**

```
HOPOPT
ICMPv4
IGMP
TCP
UDP
IPv6
IPv6-Route
IPv6-Frag
GRE
ICMPv6
IPv6-NoNxt
IPv6-Opts
VRRP
PGM
L2TP
```

---

How to find the right protocol for each address and what to choose in firewall settings?

Comment: The syntax `- Protocol TCP` is invalid because you have a space between `-` and `Protocol`. Try `-Protocol TCP`.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I correct that now is -Protocol and still getting the same error.

Comment: Is there some command that I can use and get Protocol for specific address 3.250.243.64/26 ...?

Comment: Try creating two separate rules (one per local port) instead

Comment: I figure it by using the Advanced Port Scanner. It shows Ports and Protocol used by IP